# Women's versus Men's pay in majors

Tags: tennis, finances

Why are women compensated the exact same as men in major tournaments but only play maximum three sets to men's five? I don't find that to be equal?

Answer (score 0):

Because apparently the ITF would like to make a stand by honoring men's and women's effort equally. Obviously, they were not aiming at an equal hourly wage, but at an equal reward for making it to the same round.

Did you just really sign up to SE to express your concerns about men being discriminated? Don't get me wrong, one can make the point that pay per time is lower for tennis players in major tournaments. But this is quite an uncommon standard in sports. By that standard, decathlon athletes, who arguably train most among all professional athletes (and have very long competitions), should be paid most. Professional football players, on the other hand, rarely spend more than 20 hours per week training and playing, and are paid millions in the best leagues.

Comment: Small correction: the tennis majors are organised by the ITF, not by the WTF or ATP.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. But wouldn't it be the WTA? ;)